# difference between item[] and item.fields[]

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, splistitem, spfield, splist

I want to retrieve let's say the title field of my item so what's the différence between doing these acces methods :

```
SPList myList = properties.List;
       string mytitle1 = myList.Items[0]["Title"];
       string mytitle2 = myList.Items[0].Fields["Title"];
       string mytitle3 = myList.Items[0].Fields.GetField("Title");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item[]` returns the content of the field in item
`Item.Fields[]` returns metadata about the field and not the value

Comment: how about Item.Fields.GetField("Title") ?

Comment: It returns metadata like `Item.Fields[]` the difference is that `Item.Fields[]` only does lookup by DisplayName, where `Item.Fields.GetField()` does it by InternalName, DisplayName, StaticName in that order